# MFC dialog could not load IDR_MAINFRAME correctly

Tags: winapi, mfc

My project (dialog based) previously configured as 32 bit. Now I confgure it as a 64 bit application.
But the application is missing from both the main dialog and about dialog.

When debugging I can see m_hIcon was NULL after this line in constructor of the main dialog:

```
m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
```

I tried to call GetLastError, but it returned 0. I even tried:

```
m_hIcon = LoadIcon(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME));
auto lastError = GetLastError();
```

unfortunately, the `lastError` was also 0.

The application uses WinSparkle, and the output windows of VC2019 shows:

> Microsoft C++ exception: winsparkle::Win32Exception at memory location
> 0x000000800836E408. WinSparkle: Executable doesn't have the required
> VERSIONINFO resource: The specified image file did not contain a
> resource section. Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9F0204F99 in
> XXXX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winsparkle::Win32Exception at
> memory location 0x000000800836DF18. WinSparkle: Executable doesn't
> have the required VERSIONINFO resource: The specified image file did
> not contain a resource section.

So my questions:

1. What could I do to fix the missing app icon?
2. Why GetLastError returns 0? How can I find what happens underlying?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your icon resource? And what are the values of `SM_CXICON` and `SM_CYICON` (use the [`GetSystemMetrics()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) to find these)?

Comment: @AdrianMole The dimensions of icon is 128*128, SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON are both 48. I tried to replace my icon with the default MFC icon, but didn't work.

Comment: Hmm. Note [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona): *LoadIcon can only load an icon whose size conforms to the SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON system metric values.* (And MFC's `CWinApp::LoadIcon` just wraps the generic WinAPI function.)

Comment: @AdrianMole interesting, 1) it worked all the time with 32bit configuration, 2) It didn't work when I replaced it by the default MFC icon which is 24*24.

Comment: Try adding a 48x48 image to your icon. Just a dummy one, to test if it works.

Comment: Also, I just looked at some old MFC project with the default MFC icon in them: they have a collection of images, including ones with dimensions of 48x48, 32x32, 24x24 and 16x16. You would normally have multiple images in an icon file, of different sizes and different bit-depths.

Comment: Are you sure your resources get linked into the executable?

Comment: @AdrianMole My project was created by VC2015 and upgraded to VC2019.

Comment: @IInspectable How can I make the resources get linked?

Comment: @AdrianMole I assume the one worked for the newly created MFC dialog project should work in my project, so I replaced my icon with the default MFC icon, but it still didn't work.

Comment: By specifying it as a linker input.

Comment: @IInspectable I compared vcxproj, didn't find any differences between Win32 and x64. Both have "    <ResourceCompile>
      <Culture>0x0804</Culture>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(IntDir);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ResourceCompile>
". Do you have any idea about the reason GetLastError returns 0?

Comment: Those are compiler settings, not linker settings.

Comment: @IInspectable I use `Resource Hacker` comparing 32bit exe and 64bit exe, they are identical, both have `Icon` node, and the icon in the about dialog is displaying correctly in `Resource Hacker`.

Comment: Problem resolved, there are some code changing PEB of process, after I comment the code it works now. I think the piece of code needs to be migrated into x64.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem, my application tries to modify PEB itself before `m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);`, it causes `LoadIcon` not working. It works correctly with win32 configuration but not for x64 configuration.

After I move the PEB modification logic after `LoadIcon` call, the main dialog has icon now, and tray icon can also show on windows task bar. However, the icon on AboutDialog is still not displaying correctly because it is created dynamically everytime.